# Jooq and postgres: pg_trgm operators in plain sql produce error "operator does not exist"

Tags: java, postgresql, jooq, pg-trgm

Technologies I am using: java, spring boot, jooq, postgres with pg_trgm extension, r2dbc.

I am trying to use pg_trgm operators for a simple search on Postgres, but jooq throws an error.

Code sample:

```
String searchKeyword = "something";
DSL.select(Tables.EXAMPLE.ID)
          .from(Tables.EXAMPLE)
          .where(DSL.condition("{0} <<% {1}", DSL.val(searchKeyword), Tables.EXAMPLE.TEXT_FIELD))
```

or even simpler:

```
DSL.resultQuery("select 'a' <<% 'a';")
```

Produces the error `operator does not exist: character varying <<% text`.

stacktrace:

```
org.jooq.exception.DataAccessException: SQL [select 'a' <<% 'a';]; operator does not exist: unknown <<% unknown

Original Stack Trace:
        at org.jooq.impl.Tools.translate(Tools.java:3470)
        at org.jooq.impl.Tools.translate(Tools.java:3448)
        at org.jooq.impl.Tools.translate(Tools.java:3432)
        at org.jooq.impl.R2DBC$Forwarding.lambda$onError$0(R2DBC.java:252)      at org.jooq.impl.Internal$1.onComplete(Internal.java:497)
        at reactor.core.publisher.StrictSubscriber.onComplete(StrictSubscriber.java:123)
        at org.springframework.security.test.context.support.ReactorContextTestExecutionListener$DelegateTestExecutionListener$SecuritySubContext.onComplete(ReactorContextTestExecutionListener.java:130)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber.onComplete(FluxPeekFuseable.java:277)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.onComplete(Operators.java:2060)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.onComplete(MonoIgnoreThen.java:209)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.onComplete(MonoIgnoreThen.java:209)
        at reactor.pool.SimpleDequePool.maybeRecycleAndDrain(SimpleDequePool.java:533)
        at reactor.pool.SimpleDequePool$QueuePoolRecyclerInner.onComplete(SimpleDequePool.java:765)
        at org.springframework.security.test.context.support.ReactorContextTestExecutionListener$DelegateTestExecutionListener$SecuritySubContext.onComplete(ReactorContextTestExecutionListener.java:130)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators.complete(Operators.java:137)        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoEmpty.subscribe(MonoEmpty.java:46)        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4490)
        at reactor.pool.SimpleDequePool$QueuePoolRecyclerMono.subscribe(SimpleDequePool.java:877)       at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:53)        at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64)      at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.subscribeNext(MonoIgnoreThen.java:240)      at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.onComplete(MonoIgnoreThen.java:203)         at org.springframework.security.test.context.support.ReactorContextTestExecutionListener$DelegateTestExecutionListener$SecuritySubContext.onComplete(ReactorContextTestExecutionListener.java:130)      at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onComplete(FluxPeek.java:260)         at reactor.core.publisher.Operators.complete(Operators.java:137)        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoEmpty.subscribe(MonoEmpty.java:46)        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4490)        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.subscribeNext(MonoIgnoreThen.java:263)      at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen.subscribe(MonoIgnoreThen.java:51)      at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64)      at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:53)        at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64)      at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.subscribeNext(MonoIgnoreThen.java:240)      at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.onComplete(MonoIgnoreThen.java:203)         at org.springframework.security.test.context.support.ReactorContextTestExecutionListener$DelegateTestExecutionListener$SecuritySubContext.onComplete(ReactorContextTestExecutionListener.java:130)      at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreElements$IgnoreElementsSubscriber.onComplete(MonoIgnoreElements.java:89)        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxHandleFuseable$HandleFuseableSubscriber.onComplete(FluxHandleFuseable.java:236)       at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1840)        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoSupplier.subscribe(MonoSupplier.java:62)      at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4490)        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.subscribeNext(MonoIgnoreThen.java:263)      at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen.subscribe(MonoIgnoreThen.java:51)      at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64)      at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:53)        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4490)        at org.jooq.impl.R2DBC$AbstractNonBlockingSubscription.lambda$cancel0$4(R2DBC.java:663)         at java.base/java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReference.updateAndGet(AtomicReference.java:210)         at org.jooq.impl.R2DBC$AbstractNonBlockingSubscription.cancel0(R2DBC.java:647)      at org.jooq.impl.R2DBC$AbstractSubscription.complete(R2DBC.java:213)        at org.jooq.impl.R2DBC$AbstractResultSubscriber.complete(R2DBC.java:303)        at org.jooq.impl.R2DBC$Forwarding.complete(R2DBC.java:265)      at org.jooq.impl.R2DBC$Forwarding.onError(R2DBC.java:252)       at reactor.core.publisher.StrictSubscriber.onError(StrictSubscriber.java:106)       at org.springframework.security.test.context.support.ReactorContextTestExecutionListener$DelegateTestExecutionListener$SecuritySubContext.onError Caused by: io.r2dbc.postgresql.ExceptionFactory$PostgresqlBadGrammarException: [42883] operator does not exist: unknown <<% unknown   at io.r2dbc.postgresql.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:96)   Suppressed: The stacktrace has been enhanced by Reactor, refer to additional information below:  Assembly trace from producer [reactor.core.publisher.FluxHandleFuseable] :     reactor.core.publisher.Flux.handle(Flux.java:5913)  io.r2dbc.postgresql.PostgresqlResult.map(PostgresqlResult.java:107) Error has been observed at the following site(s):   *__Flux.handle ⇢ at io.r2dbc.postgresql.PostgresqlResult.map(PostgresqlResult.java:107) Original Stack Trace:       at io.r2dbc.postgresql.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:96)       at io.r2dbc.postgresql.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:65)       at io.r2dbc.postgresql.ExceptionFactory.handleErrorResponse(ExceptionFactory.java:132)      at io.r2dbc.postgresql.PostgresqlResult.lambda$map$2(PostgresqlResult.java:111)         at reactor.core.publisher.FluxHandleFuseable$HandleFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxHandleFuseable.java:176)       at reactor.core.publisher.FluxWindowPredicate$WindowFlux.drainRegular(FluxWindowPredicate.java:668)         at reactor.core.publisher.FluxWindowPredicate$WindowFlux.drain(FluxWindowPredicate.java:746)        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxWindowPredicate$WindowFlux.onNext(FluxWindowPredicate.java:788)       at reactor.core.publisher.FluxWindowPredicate$WindowPredicateMain.onNext(FluxWindowPredicate.java:239)      at io.r2dbc.postgresql.util.FluxDiscardOnCancel$FluxDiscardOnCancelSubscriber.onNext(FluxDiscardOnCancel.java:91)
```

Note that the following plain sql query works if ran directly on the DB:

```
select id from example where 'something' <<% text_field;
```

Also note: it is not a type cast issue. If I cast the searchKeyword to text, or if I inline it, a similar error is produced

Another note: if I change the code to use the strict_word_similarity function instead of the operator, it works. The issue is only with the operator

Comment: Either you aren't connected to the same database between the two tests, or you don't have the same search_path settings.

Comment: Please see my last edit. The issue is only with the operator @jjanes

Comment: Can you look in the db server's log file to get the error from there?  Maybe the operator name has some weird character in there which doesn't belong, and then it is also not showing up in the error message as massaged by the client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can cast your bind variable to text explicitly:

```java
DSL.condition("{0}::text <<% {1}", ...)
```

Or inline it instead of binding it:

```java
DSL.condition("{0} <<% {1}", DSL.inline(searchKeyword), Tables.EXAMPLE.TEXT_FIELD)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but both solutions produce the above error: operator does not exist: text <<% text or operator does not exist: unknown <<% text

Comment: @fedpet: Did you `CREATE EXTENSION pg_trgm;` on the database you're working on? What does `select * from pg_operator where oprname = '<<%';` yield?

Comment: yes I did, the select returns a record about the strict_word_similarity operator as it should. If I change the jooq code to use the strict_word_similarity function it works. But I want to use the operator @LukasEder

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know. This seems `pg_trgm` specific. You'll probably get the same error when querying with JDBC directly?

Comment: I'm using r2dbc, but I don't get the exception if I put the query in a repository method with the Query annotation. It works as expected @LukasEder

Comment: @fedpet: Well, I can't reproduce the issue. With latest versions of everything, `Flux.from(ctx.resultQuery("select 'a' <<% 'a'"))` works just fine for me.

Comment: after a lot of debugging the issue was indeed that the search_path was set incorrectly for this scenario... sorry for wasting time, and thanks for the help